# When was oracle DB timezone last updated

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

Is there any way we can check when was the timezone setting change happened in oracle , like exact date and time ?

Comment: you could probably look at the date/time on the timezone file at the OS level. That would give a lower limit as to when it was updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "timezone setting"? Modification of `DBTIMEZONE` requires a database restart, this you should be able to find out. It should not affect your application anyway.